# Android : Add text to create a list with image at the top.

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface

I am working on an Android application in which I am working on letting the user add some text below the image, and then the text will be saved in the database on server. The user must be able to add text as shown in the screenshot below. Please note that the user can decide that the text entered can go below the screen as well.

Mock image(Apologies for my horrible Gimp skills... :D )

[image]

Now as you can see on the top, there will be a header image with which the the display will start with. Then below that I would like to put additional `EditText` fields ideally, but the problem is that the user can go on entering the text, and the EditText field might get over. This is the first problem I am tackling. The only way I could think of is to add an `EditText` via code in a loop or after a scroll, etc. Any other solutions for the same.

The 2nd problem is I will save all the text information on our server, but how will I properly align that information as it was entered by the first user and display them for the 2nd user.

Kindly let me know if there are any better solutions for the first problem and a strategy for the 2nd problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you can do this - Add an `ImageView` and an `EditText` below it. Add a `TextWatcher` to the EditText to listen for user input. If the user enters some text, dynamically add another `EditText` below it. If the user clears the text, remove that `EditText` from the layout. Do the same for all `EditText`s.

As for saving the text on your backend, you can number the text fields internally and save them on your server. When you retrieve this data, the numbers will indicate the order of the text.

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                // Add EditText to the list
            } else {
                // Remove the EditText from the list
            }
        }
    });
```

You can base your further handling logic around this snippet. For example, remove the EditText when it is empty AND it loses focus...

Comment: How will I display the text as it was saved? Also, how can I add an EditText after a few lines when the user is typing?

Comment: You can use a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` to easily add and remove `EditText`s. See the `TextWatcher` docs for more info. Also, what do you mean by "display text as it was saved" ? Do you mean that you want the 2nd user to see the text as soon as it is saved to the server ?

Comment: The user can always later see it. But the whole point of doing this is, that the first user enters information in a specific manner and its displayed in the same manner to the user who is trying to view it. So, for display, what do I do? Add textFields, image of the text, etc?

Comment: Load data from your server and use `TextView`s. You can replace the `EditText`s of the first user with `TextView`s.

Comment: I will try out both of these approaches and be back.